# Text Categorization on bilingual raw data

Tags: python-3.x, text-processing, knn

I have a CSV file with more than 10000 rows.

I'm trying to segregate the text in one particular column('short_desctiption') based on their natural language.

Most of the texts have a standard format like (German text // English text) but some times either one of the language is missing or the format is not in order.

please suggest a way to categorize two columns for each language

```
print(data_sel[['number','short_description']].head(5))
```

And the output looks like:

```
       number                                  short_description
0  INC37263694 Internet geht nicht//Internet is not working
1  INC4836555  OUTLOOK Benutzung nicht möglich // unable to user outlook
2  INC3981320  Ich habe Problem emich im Igel anzumelden 
3  INC5579940  forgot password // Hat Kennwort vergessen
4  INC4882640  Agent Desktop doest start, the desktops are changed
```

Comment: This is not a programming problem, but a linguistic problem. However the package `Natural Language Toolkit` should be useful here. You can download an English dictionary from it. NLTK: https://www.nltk.org/ Detecting the language of a string is also possible via the Google Cloud Translation API: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language

Comment: Thank you for your comment. can you please explain to this specific code above with a short example from nltk libraries. – @tommy.carstensen .